# How does one configure azure web apps to display custom error pages?

Tags: azure, web, vue.js

I've got a small Vue test project created with the Vue Cli. Made a production build with npm build.

The site is up and running, but the 204 and 404 status codes doesn't reach my app (Display my error page).

After some research my current understanding is that I have to set up a
web.config file, like in ASP.NET, something along the line:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
         <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
             <httpErrors 
errorMode="Custom"existingResponse="PassThrough">
    <clear />
    <error statusCode="400" path="index.html"
responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

1. I'm not sure which file to refer to in the 'path'. My error page is a component, but vue renders it all to index.html so thats my guess.
2. Where to put the web.config file when deploying. I've tried putting it in the dist folder.
3. Is it possible to just configure in Azure instead of creating a web.config?

My attempts has been unsuccessful..

I'm deploying via Visual Code (via the Azure extension).

Anyone who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Custom error page can be another .html page. However, since you have the Vue component taking care of that, you need not configure this on the Azure/web.config unless you have the route based URL for the error page in your Vue component.

If you have the route based error page in your Vue app, put the error page URL within the web.config's error section (if that is directly accessible). However, this may not work if the error page is not directly accessible and in case of unhandled exception.

My suggestion is to create a separate error.html file and also redirect your errors from your Vue components to that.